# Conditional change of font color based on value in a different cell

Tags: excel, colors, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

I want to change the color of the text inside a cell but in a way that is conditioned by an action in another cell, specifically insertion  of `X`. For example:

BEFORE

```
Cell A1: without text  
Cell B1: text in red
```

ACTION: `X` is inserted in cell A1

AFTER

```
Cell A1: `X`  
Cell B1: text in blue
```

Can this be done using conditional formatting or with a macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try a Conditional Formatting rule of:

```
=A1="X"
```

with Applies to:

```
=$B$1
```

and blue font. (This will override a 'standard' formatting of red font for B1 when A1 is populated with `X`.)

Comment: Worked perfectly! If i want to aply that rule to columns how could that be done? Ex. B1 depending on A1, B2 depending on A2, C3 depending on A3, etc. Only with one rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can.

```
If Range("A1") = "" Then
    Range("B1").Font.Color = vbRed
else
   Range("B1").Font.Color = vbBlue
End If
```

if its purely for the "x" change the 'else' line to this

```
ElseIf Range("A1") = "X"
```